# Multiple Dropdowns with Button

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I currently have two dropdown boxes, I was wondering if someone can assist on how I can join the two output values into one sentence, once the user presses a button.

This is the code I am currently working with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="action_page.php">
            <select id="selectcars" name="cars">
                <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <div class="text-for-car" id="volvo">Your text for "Volvo"</div>
        <div class="text-for-car" id="saab">Your text for "Saab"</div>
        <div class="text-for-car" id="fiat">Your text for "Fiat"</div>
        <div class="text-for-car" id="audi">Your text for "Audi"</div>
        <style>
            .text-for-car {display: none;}
            #volvo {display: block;}
        </style>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("selectcars").addEventListener("change", function () {
                var id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
                var texts = document.getElementsByClassName("text-for-car");
                for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
                if (texts[i].id == id) texts[i].style.display = "block";
                else texts[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            })
        </script>
        <form>
            <select id="selectcars2" name="cars2">
                <option value="volvo2" selected>Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab2">Saab</option>
                <option value="fiat2">Fiat</option>
                <option value="audi2">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <div class="text-for-car2" id="volvo2">Your text for "Volvo"</div>
        <div class="text-for-car2" id="saab2">Your text for "Saab"</div>
        <div class="text-for-car2" id="fiat2">Your text for "Fiat"</div>
        <div class="text-for-car2" id="audi2">Your text for "Audi"</div>
        <style>
            .text-for-car2 {display: none;}
            #volvo2 {display: block;}
        </style>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("selectcars2").addEventListener("change", function () {
                var id2 = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
                var texts2 = document.getElementsByClassName("text-for-car2");
                for (var i = 0; i < texts2.length; i++) {
                if (texts2[i].id == id2) texts2[i].style.display = "block";
                else texts2[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your demo is a bit long and I don't want to separate everything, but I made a quick demo there that should help you with your question.

http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/JRxqPG

```
<label for="car">Car</label>
<select id="car">
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<label for="engine">Engine</label>
<select id="engine">
  <option value="1.4 Petrol">1.4 Petrol</option>
  <option value="1.6 Petrol">1.6 Petrol</option>
  <option value="2.0 TDI">2.0 TDI</option>
</select>

<p>You have chosen a <span class="car">Ford </span> with a <span class="engine">1.4 Petrol</span> engine.</p>

$('#car').on('change', function() {
  var s = $(this).val();
  console.log(s);
  $('p .car').text(s);
});

$('#engine').on('change', function() {
  var s = $(this).val();
  console.log(s);
  $('p .engine').text(s);
});
```

Comment: Here I did on change, but you could easily attach the event to a button.

Comment: Thanks so much! Is the above SEO friendly, as the text in each instance would be 70 to 10 words long.

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello World!')">Process</button>

Comment: Sorry!, Pressing 'enter' didn't skip to the next line. Would wrapping the change function within the above button code suffice?

Comment: Okay, I changed it to update on button click:

http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/jrdowR

Does that work for you?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - thanks so much for your assistance!